# Would this question be off topic for SO?

Tags: discussion

[I can't open phpMyAdmin, get error 301 or 500](https://superuser.com/questions/561268/weird-redirect-by-phpmyadmin-on-vm/561692)

We have a discussion going [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6455/why-is-my-question-being-vtced/6457) about this being off topic. Others are saying it may fit in another site better. I'm trying to figure out if this would be on topic for Stack Overflow, and if not, are there any relevant meta posts explaining why?

Comment: I would say it's off-topic for SO. What makes you think it's on-topic? Does anything in the FAQ give you that idea?

Comment: Nothing in the FAQ makes me think it does belong here, but doesn't specifically make me think it's off topic. I personally think it's OT for SO, but we had a vote to migrate on it. I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: *"a specific programming problem"* Nope, *"a software algorithm"* Nope, *"software tools commonly used by programmers*" Nope. So not on-topic.

Comment: @Bart Works for me. Wasn't sure if one could argue that phpMyAdmin is more commonly used by developers...

Answer (score 1):

Serverfault may be better. Stackoverflow focuses on programming questions. While we typically allow that to leak to developer things, PHPMyAdmin isn't developer specific.

EDIT:

To expand on what I mean by leaking, I mean things that developers use but would be categorized elsewhere if it weren't a developer product.

For instance configuring a browser add-in would be super user, however configuring [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) a Visual Studio add-in, may be allowed.

Since PHPMyAdmin isn't a developer product, it doesn't fall under that exception clause. Keep in mind that PHPMyAdmin is a tool developers use, but not a developer product.

Comment: This isn't Server Fault material: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity/4112#4112

Comment: [webmasters.se] might be the best bet?